# Can HTML be used in AXML files?

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, ionic-framework, cross-platform

I'm new to Cross-Platform development in Visual Studio Xamarin.  And first thing I noticed was this **axml** files, which in my opinion is the view of a controller in MVC terminology.  I want to transfer my Ionic-Cordova App to Xamarin, but having problems in design part, since i'm not sure on how to implement the html files (or the views).  Having said that, is there a faster way on how to convert my **html** files into **axml** files?  Or is there an efficient way on my part in transferring Ionic-cordova app to Xamarin? like reusing all html and js files (controllers/services/app)?

Comment: Short answer: No, longer answer: You could always use an embedded WebView to reuse your html/javascript and build a native app/framework around the "embedded browser".... but, IMHO, that would kind-of defeat going to a native app/solution, vs. a hybrid one like Ionic-Cordova as you would be rebuilding that environment into a Xamarin-Based one...

Comment: aaah okay thanks sir @SushiHangover i'll just delete this dumb question